# Is it possible to hijack specific e-mail with remote access?

Tags: email, email-spoofing, ip-spoofing, fraud

I was recently presented with e-mails that look like they came from my e-mail and IP address but I didn't send them and never saw them. It is a back and forth correspondence with another gmail account. Is it possible someone was able to set up a forwarding without my knowing and make it look like it was coming to and from me?  I did find that someone had snuck in AnyDesk and had remote access to my laptop during this time, so they had access to everything.

I am a clinical psychologist. I was treating a woman in an abusive relationship. Built up her self-esteem enough that she has finally gotten out of that relationship and is divorcing him. He has filed a complaint that we had a romantic relationship and created these e-mails to support that. He doesn't like me for putting ideas in her head (like she's not worthless), but this also plays in his favor in the custody battle. Just looking for plausible explanations for how these could be faked.

Comment: I think you answered your own question there: "they had access to everything."  That's an affirmative

Comment: If they had access to everything, there might still be backdoors left. Only way to be sure is a complete reinstallation. Also, you need to figure out how they got it there in the first place and improve your security accordingly.

Comment: "If someone copied my car keys, could they take my car for a spin without me knowing?" -- Yes. Without more technical details, we can't be more specific. The problem here is not the emails (the joy-riding) but how they got access and what *else* they might have done. If in the USA, you might have HIPAA disclosure procedures, in the EU, GDPR. There are much bigger things you need to address.